# Can I test if a file descriptor is of the right type for read()?

Tags: sockets, unix, posix, xsi

There are plenty of fds that can't be read from (for example, a listening socket). How do I test whether a `read`(2) on the fd will return `EINVAL`, without risking taking data out?

#### Things that don't work:

1. We could do a `read()` with a zero-byte buffer passed. This is ruled out though:

   > Implementations are allowed, but not required, to perform error checking for `read()` requests of zero bytes. [From POSIX 1003.1-2008]
2. We might be tempted to call `select()` on the descriptor. Unfortunately, `select()` has very overloaded semantics for the readable set, so will tell that an fd is "readable" when in fact it's an error to call `read()` on it (for example, a listening socket will be marked "readable" but needs `accept()`, not `read()`, and there are other non-portable examples like event or kqueue fds).
3. (Sort of works) Read manpages for every platform you compile on test the fd with specific system calls to produce a function that looks roughly like:

   ```
   int isReadable(int fd)
   { return isActiveSocket(fd) || isFifo(fd) || isRegFile(fd) ||
              isEventFd(fd) || ... /* more pain */ }
   ```
4. (Sort of works) Note that `read()` itself doesn't necessarily give you a nice answer as to whether the fd was the right type for the system call! Surprisingly, `EINVAL` is unspecified in POSIX for `read()` (except on STREAMS), but is given to you on linux ("EINVAL: fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for reading") and rather mysteriously on BSD ("EINVAL: The pointer associated with [the fd] was negative.").

#### Scenarios

Someone launches your application, and you want to know whether the fd with value 0 is bogus (eg a listening socket) or whether it's ever going to possible to read from it. You'd like to do without trying an actual `read()` a) because that blocks, b) because after taking the data out you can't stuff it back in.

Comment: `man select`, `man poll`, `man epoll`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that answers the question. I have an fd and I want to know if it's of a type suitable for reading, not whether it's "ready" in the select sense (which might indicate I need to call accept or some totally other API).

Comment: Your program shouldn't be organized in such a way that there is any doubt about it.

Comment: @EJP Because..? Suppose clients pass fds to a daemon, and it wants to do a rough check it's a suitable descriptor. At the moment, I reject everything except active sockets, but I'd like to let through fifos, regular files, etc without having to code in all the sorts of fd on each platform. You might still think I'm wrong, but do you have an answer to the question, which is at least interesting.

Comment: @NicholasWilson The reason is simply that there is no reliable way to do this check. You could only accomplish it through a bit of heuristics (which may fail when someone changes stuff in the kernel in the future - that's the price to pay when trying to use non standard/specified features). e.g. there's a getsockopt() to figure out if the socket is a listening socket. Some OSs will allow you to query the descriptor kind with fstat() for some classes of descriptors, and so on.

Comment: @nos Thanks, that's what I was realistically resigned to. I'd accept that comment if you made it an answer and close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You quoted the relevant part of the specification yourself.

Indeed, a read may fail at any time for any number of reasons. Testing for "will read succeed", followed by a `read`, merely introduces a race condition - the situation may change in between the two calls.

You need to write your application in such a way that a failed read is handled appropriately. If you do that, you won't usually need to care about testing beforehand, and can simply use `select` to determine when data is (probably) available.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you cannot use fcntl with the F_GETXFL option?

```
int isread(int fd)
{
   int o_accmode=0;
   int rc=fcntl(fd, F_GETXFL, &o_accmode);
   if(rc == -1 )
       return rc;
   rc=(o_accmode & O_ACCMODE);
   return (rc==O_RDONLY || rc==RDWR);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Learn something new every day. I can find it on Solaris, and it's mentioned in the Darwin and FreeBSD headers but doesn't seem to be implemented. Are there any other platforms I can use this on? I need to read up on its exact semantics in OpenSolaris... I wonder what it gives you for pipes, socketpair, fifos, ...

Comment: fcntl is POSIX. A lot of linux versions support it.  F_GETFL is POSIX.  F_GETXFL is not.  It should show up for you anyplace that claims POSIXness.  Almost any fd works for this, with the exception of  fd's for oddball things like doors may not.  It does not work for typed  memory objects.  It does work for mmap-ed files, though.

Comment: POSIX: `F_GETFL` instead of `F_GETXFL` and `O_RDWR` instead of `RDWR`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest is to use `select`:

```
int
is_valid_descriptor( int fd )
{
  fd_set rd;
  struct timeval t = { 0, 0 };
  FD_ZERO( &rd );
  FD_SET( fd, &rd );
  return -1 != select( fd + 1, &rd, NULL, NULL, &t );
}
```

Note that this does not indicate whether or not a read will block (it's not clear what you mean by "succeed").

Comment: No, select will happily tell you that a listening socket is readable, but read gives you EINVAL/EBADF. There are squillions of other fd types on different unixes, so using fstat+getsockopt to weed out listening sockets isn't good enough; that's just one example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're okay with calling recv() instead of read() (they are typically interchangeable for sockets), you can supply MSG_PEEK in the flags argument and the recv() call will act as usual except that it won't actually remove any bytes from the socket's internal buffer.  You might be able to use that to catch errors without altering the socket's internal state.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works with sockets, as far as I'm aware, so wouldn't help me tell the difference between, for example, an epoll fd and a regular file fd.