# Is this a portable way to make a stack buffer eight-byte aligned?

Tags: c

```
struct {
  uint64_t a; char z[120];
} b;

...

struct buffer_with_alignment_requirement* c = (struct buffer_w*)&b;
c->start_using_it;
```

Without the first member `a`, we might crash when accessing fields in the buffer. Is it portable and correct to simply add a member like this to force aligment for the whole struct to be strict enough?

This is not a question about pointer aliasing, simply about whether the address of `b` on the stack is always eight-byte aligned.

Comment: No - it depends on the platform, the compiler, and compiler switches.

Comment: What OS?  posix_memalign and memalign will enforce alignment for you in in Linux/UNIX.

Comment: @jim I want it on the stack, not dynamically. If I were going that way, plain malloc would be good enough for me right now, actually (malloc always returns int-aligned memory). OSes: Jenkins job runs on BSD, Solaris, Darwin, Linux, AIX, and Windows, with build machines a mixture of Power, x86, amd64, one SPARC, one PA-RISC, and one ia64 (no ARM at the moment yet for this project).

Comment: SO is unbelievable! I'd downvote my own post if I could. 5 upvotes in ten minutes for question that's basically "let me google that in the standard for you". My last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294518/) was actually interesting and gets ignored :(.

Comment: why don't you just use compiler pragmas for alignment ?

Comment: One approach is using an `union`. Thay way you could throw in more types like `double` (which could have higher alignment requirements than `uint64_t`) and you would not waste space as the members share space with the actual buffer.

Comment: @NicholasWilson I suppose it's because the `C` tag is much more followed than the `sockets`, `unix` or `posix` tags.

Comment: @Mellowcandle compiler pragmas are typically non-portable, and few, if any compielrs have pragmas for alignment. (e.g. the more commonly implemented  #pragma pack does not solve the problem of the OP).

Comment: If `int64_t` doesn't have 8-byte alignment, you probably don't *need* 8-byte alignment.

Comment: Yes, ideally we would just use the correct struct from the start! Subsequent code might determine the type though (eg the classic prototype functions where you pass in a sockaddr_storage* and the caller can't decide what type it is). I'll use a union with a double to force my alignment. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by aligned. If you want `(uintptr_t)&b % 8 == 0`, there is **no portable way** to obtain this, as the conversion from pointer to integer is implementation-defined and need not be any sane, natural mapping.

If all you want is for the buffer to be sufficiently aligned for access with type `uint64_t`, your solution works perfectly well. But why don't you just use (possibly an array of) type `struct buffer_with_alignment_requirement`, rather than the ugly union hackery? In other words, just give the buffer the right type you intend to access it as to begin with. You can pass a pointer to any type to `read`, `fread`, `revc`, etc. and other functions that you might be using to write into the buffer, and even if you'll be passing it to a function that expects a buffer pointer of type `char *` or `unsigned char *`, you can just cast when passing it; this cast is perfectly well-defined and valid.

Answer (score 3):

The exact-width integer types, if they exist (7.20.1.1p3), do not have any particular alignment requirements other than that they should be at least as aligned as `char` and no more aligned than `max_align_t` (6.2.8p2-4).  There is not even any requirement that alignment should follow integer conversion rank, except of course that corresponding signed and unsigned types should have the same alignment (6.2.5p6).

If you want a particular alignment, use an alignment specifier:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
struct alignas(8) {
  char z[120];
} b;
```

However, presumably given your description of accessing fields, what you *actually* want is for the buffer to be aligned to the most aligned type that could exist within the buffer.  To do this C11 provides `max_align_t`; in older compilers you can emulate `max_align_t` using a union of the standard types:

```
typedef union {
  char c;
  short s;
  int i;
  long l;
  long long ll;  // if available
  float f;
  double d;
  long double ld;  // if available
  void *p;
  void (*fun)();
} max_align_t;
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `_Alignas`?

Comment: Okay, that works too. I prefer to use the keyword here, though. (Odd, since I much prefer to `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `bool` over `_Bool`.)

Comment: OK, so what about code like this: http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/socket.h?v=GLIBC27#L159 (sockaddr_storage) I've seen that sort of thing done in the code of supposedly portable applications too. If you used a literal double instead of a uint64_t, would you be happy with the trick then? I don't have stdalign.h on all my platforms.

Comment: @NicholasWilson there's also no requirement that `double` be aligned to 8 bytes, so whether that works depends on the platform (often, "portable" just means portable to "standard" platforms).

Comment: @NicholasWilson you could just use (or emulate) `max_align_t`; see above.

Answer (score 2):

No, the C standard leaves alignment at the discression of the compiler.

In practice, many compilers will align the struct 8-byte aligned, but they are not required to do so.