# How to check alignment of returned data in the malloc() implementation?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

`malloc(sz)` returns memory whose alignment works for any object.

On 32-bit x86 machines, this means that the address value returned by `malloc()`must be evenly divisible by 4. But in practice, 32-bit malloc implementations return 8-byte aligned memory, meaning that returned addresses are always evenly divisible by 8. You should do this too. (On x86-64/IA-64 machines, the maximum data alignment is 8, but malloc implementations return 16-byte aligned memory.)

I have a test for this situation

```
// Check alignment of returned data.

 int main() 
 {
     double* ptr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));
     assert((uintptr_t) ptr % __alignof__(double) == 0);
     assert((uintptr_t) ptr % __alignof__(unsigned long long) == 0);

     char* ptr2 = (char*) malloc(1);
     assert((uintptr_t) ptr2 % __alignof__(double) == 0);
     assert((uintptr_t) ptr2 % __alignof__(unsigned long long) == 0);
  }
```

My malloc code allocate more space than the user requested. The first part of that space is used to store metadata about the allocation, including the allocated size.

`sizeof(metadata) % 8 == 0`

But my heap

```
 static char heap[Heap_Capacity];
```

starting with value that not divided by 8

```
metadata* block = (metadata*)heap;
(uintptr_t)block % 8 != 0
```

My tests fails, what can I do in this situation?
How to be sure that the array begins with address that

```
metadata* block = (metadata*)heap;
(uintptr_t)block % 8 == 0
```

?

Comment: Since you've tagged it C++, use `std::aligned_storage`. Or was that tag a mistake?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ok, thanks. __alignof__ doesn't work in c++ ?

Comment: Are you asking how to check the alignment of a buffer returned from `malloc()` or how to force a particular alignment on a statically allocated (or automatic) buffer?  The possible solutions are different, and the last few lines in the question suggest the latter.

Comment: @Anatoly: Yes, C++ has `alignof`.

Comment: Anatoly - Mike is saying you can just use [std::aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) if you're really using C++.

Comment: C11 has `max_align_t` which has the greatest aliment needs.

Comment: There's `alignas` in C11 as well, e.g. `alignas(8) static char heap[Heap_Capacity];`. An older trick is to store the thing-to-be-aligned together with some sufficiently-aligned type in a `union`, which guarantees the same alignment as for that type. There's likely to be compiler-specific alignment directives as well.

Comment: `alignas` requires `<stdalign.h>` to be included by the way. Otherwise you have to spell it `_Alignas`.

Comment: In C11 - in C++11, `alignas` is a keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16339908/2410359 may be useful

Comment: There is no difference because both of this functions returns 8

Comment: How about a simple `metadata* block = (metadata*)((((uint64_t)heap-1)/8+1)*8)`? Of course, you will have to take into account that not all `Heap_Capacity` bytes are available to you. Note that I've used `8` just in order to make it more readable in this comment, and that you should basically use `sizeof(uint64_t)` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you can declare `static uint64_t heap[Heap_Capacity/sizeof(uint64_t)]`. This will guarantee that your heap is properly aligned.

Comment: @barak manos  1) Likely needs `uint64_t heap[(Heap_Capacity + sizeof(uint64_t) - 1)/sizeof(uint64_t)]` as integer division truncates.  2) "guarantee ... properly aligned" is a bit over-stated (consider `complex double`, etc.), but practically correct.

Comment: @chux: Yep, but I couldn't put this into the comment while keeping it readable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a union to force correct alignment (see [Union element alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891471/union-element-alignment)) or calculate starting index for allocation that is correctly aligned (which could reduce your heap capacity by up to 7 bytes).

Comment: As I said `sizeof(metadata) % 8 == 0`, so I dont need to use union. Problem with static char heap[Heap_Capacity];
because it start with value that not divided by 8, for example 123. So when I add to it 24, it also not divided by 8

Comment: @Anatoly: He means to make your heap itself be a union.

Comment: `union heap_union { void *v; size_t sz; long long ll; long double ld; char heap[Heap_Capacity]; } ` Then you declare `static union heap_union heap;` and use `heap.heap`. Or instead of a union, you could use compiler specific features to request that your char array need a certain alignment.